# Send scheduled reminders to relationship contact

Tags: relationships, scheduled-reminders

I have setup a webform with an organisation and individual. The form collects an email address for both the organisation and individual. The membership is only for the organisation, but the individual will login and manage the account. This part works.

I would like to send scheduled reminders for organisations membership to be sent to the individual. Is this possible? Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

two thoughts off the top of my head:

1: create a tag, apply that tag to the org contacts, use the tag to create a smartgroup; send email to the smartgroup

2: set a relationship between the org and individual (contact person is; is contact for) and set up a smartgroup that includes all individuals with an active relationship of that type

Comment: edit: 1: create a tag, apply that tag to the org contacts, should read
1: create a tag, apply that tag to the *individual* contacts,